# My Linux mini server have infinite reboot loop

Tags: linux, armbian

I made a daily reboot entry in crontab for 3 am, but it's always rebooting.

[image: wtmp log]

[image: crontab]

[image: last shutdown]

I pulled out the power cable then put it in again to make the rebooting stop.

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: is this a very old server, and is maybe the mainboard RTC battery empty?

Comment: sorry, its not  a regular server, but its a mini server, i am using STB HG680P

Comment: "armbian" ... is this some raspberry pi (or similar) without RTC? when they boot, the time is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` - and at a guess, you're timezone is GMT+7

Comment: yes its almost same, but i was checked the ntp, the time is right now

Comment: sure, but when it boots, the time will be the unix epoch, until the clock is set by NTP - so, all your system boot times would be Jan 1 1970 - this is normal

Comment: how to check it?, can i edit that?

Comment: how to check what? edit what? if your system has no real time clock, then at boot, the time will be `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` - that is not negotiable

Comment: perhaps [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1561950/cronjob-stuck-in-a-reboot-loop) will help

Comment: Thanks, sadly i should try this later at 3 am :(

Comment: or you could change the crontab entry to reboot earlier

Comment: i was already do that before, but thereis no problem, just only at night after 12 pm i think

Comment: No: when you changed the hour in the test, you must have set the minute to 0. In the image you posted, the time is clearly `* 3 * * *`.

Comment: agree, already fixed that Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You crontab entry is incorrect.

You have set it to reboot every **minute** between 03:00 and 03:59.

It does not show a reboot every minute, because it takes 2 or 3 minutes to reboot.

Comment: and the solution is, i was add the number at minute coloumn